# How do I start Microsoft Teams in Mute All Mode

Tags: meetings, microsoft-teams

**Skype for Business** allows you to start a meeting in *Mute All* mode.

**Teams.UserVoice** had this request:

> When joining a meeting, the video and mic should be turned off by
>   default and need to be turned on by the user either per session or
>   globally via settings. This is the default behavior for both Skype for
>   Business and Lync 2013 (as I recall). 
>   Mar 17, 2017 
>   COMPLETED

**Teams.UserVoice** Responded:

> Warren responded  ·  Jul 30, 2018
>   This feature request has been
>   completed and shipped!
>   Thank you for the suggestion. 
>   **-Warren**

I know when **new** Participants join a **large** (>5 people) Meeting, they start Muted.

How do I turn on the *Mute All* switch for **All** Participants as the **Default** when a Teams Meeting starts.

Comment: would like to know this too

Comment: when I and my co-workers join a meeting we are muted already automatically, maybe we can try this out? reach out to me https://tiny.cc/chagai